# Avoid serialization of properties

Tags: angularjs

When I require to add a private property to an object (for view or logic control) that will be submitted to a rest api latter, is valid prefix the property with $$? This is tricky in cases when I have an object with a list of children and each child requires a private property that should not be sent.

```
{
  name: 'my object',
  items: [
    {
      name: 'my child',
      $$editing: true
    },
    {
      name: 'my other child',
      $$editing: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, angularjs $http service uses the angular.toJson method by default.
All properties with $$ are filtered out, because angular uses such properties internally. (e.g. you may have seen the $$hashKey property, which is added by angular)

You can try:

```
console.log(angular.toJson({a:1, $$b:2, c: {x:2,$$_y:3}}))
```

results in "{"a":1,"c":{"x":2}}"